# Retrieve a list element which conatins a string that starts with '(' followed by 12 alphanumeric or special charaters and ending with ')' in python

Tags: python, regex

1. I have a .log file which contains huge no of lines, i am able to get particular lines from that file which conatins the required string through simple grep command and storing it in a .txt file
2. Now i am able to read the newly created file and split each word into a list
3. Now my requirement is to get only the string list element which starts with a '(' followed by 12 characters(generated randomly containing alphanumeric and special characters).

This is the code i have tried out upto this point.

```
import re
hand = open('ss.txt')

for line in hand:
    line = line.split(" ")
    print(line)
for ele in line:
    print(ele)    
    elementFound=re.match(r'[^(*A-Za-z*)]',ele)
print(element.groups())
```

I am getting NoneType Object in return.

Sample List where i am checking from:

```
['', '', '<error', 'value="Linux/Unix', 'Update', 'script', 'with', 'Lock/Unlock', 'user', 
  'LC_ALL:', 'cannot', 'change', 'locale', '(MysoSe7zs7nw)\\nuid=1001(linuxuser1)', 
  'gid=100(users)', 'groups=100(users)\\nUpdated','user', 'account:', 'linuxuser1\\n\\nSuccessfully', 
  'established', 'session.', 'Script', 'execution', 
  'complete\\n0\\n"/>\n']
```

I need to extract element conating (MysoSe7zs7nw) string in the above example list.

Comment: you match only letters, but `MysoSe7zs7nw` contains numbers as well

Comment: Yes...i did not know how to add numbers in regex...i tried the answer from @Blomosmetek still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `r'([(].{12}[)])'` as your regexp. Also, `print(elementFound.group(1))`

The complete code:

```
import re
with open('ss.txt', 'r') as hand:
    for line in hand:
        for ele in line.split():
            element = re.search(r'([(].{12}[)])', ele)
            if element:
                print(element.group(1))
```

Comment: tride the regex as mentioned ...got the same error...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(elementFound.groups(1)) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: is it because the entire list string is (MysoSe7zs7nw)\\nuid=1001(linuxuser1)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you should use `re.search`, not `re.match` (read the manual about the difference); also it is `.group(1)` not `.groups(1)` - see updated answer.

Comment: Tried it out with re.search() and used .group(1)...still getting the same error

Comment: Yes it worked ...Thank you for the answer...but how come by adding an if statement it is working?

Comment: The second loop goes through whitespace-separated elements of a log line. Only one of them contains a match - for others, `re.search` returns `None`.